# Forcing camera to landscape android

Tags: android, webrtc

I am developing a video chat application. everything is working just fine. The application is intended to keep the video taken by the camera in the landscape, and I am already OK with this, I could eventually make the video chat continues when the application goes to the background by the action of clicking the Home button, but since the phone Home Screen is portrait, the camera flips the video taken by it to portrait mode and this can be seen by the other peer. Is there a way to make the camera keeps recording video in landscape mode when the application goes to the background.

Comment: It's your app based on WebRTC?

Comment: yes, but that's irrelevant because the application was built on top Tokbox formerly and I decided it is a chance to learn webrtc, but when I were using tokbox I had the same issue :(

Comment: We won't fix bugs for Tokbox until they opensource their SDK ;)

Comment: But as far as WebRTC is involved, your task is "simply" to discard the piece that listens to orientation change and rotates the camera input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebRTC, the piece of code that keeps track of 'phone orientation' is a static [CameraSession.getDeviceOrientation(Context context)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/master/sdk/android/src/java/org/webrtc/CameraSession.java#42) method. Both **Camera1Session** and **Camera2Session** use this function, but you want to have same fixed return value, probably `90`.

If your code is not so far from this [WebRtcActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/vivek1794/2e3338283f46d81d0a7e04f163610a1d), you should create your private copy of **CameraEnumerator** which will override [createCapturer()](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/Camera1Enumerator.java#72) which will return a *capturer* that overrides [createCameraSession()](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/Camera1Capturer.java#27) and return your modified overload of [CameraSession](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/master/sdk/android/src/java/org/webrtc/CameraSession.java).

Unfortunately, you cannot simply inherit from  [Camera1Session](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/master/sdk/android/src/java/org/webrtc/Camera1Session.java), because it has the [call](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc.git/+/master/sdk/android/src/java/org/webrtc/Camera1Session.java#319) to **CameraSession.getDeviceOrientation()** deep in a private method.

Comment: it is harder than I thought, it can't really figure out a way to get around inheriting from the Camera1Session :( any idea

Comment: please can u help in that I can't find a way to do that

Comment: @Alex you are a rook-star but do u know how to get around this, I thought I can implement the CameraEnumerator interface, but it is a very hard task if possible

Comment: @ArmaniDarknight  I believe you can simply copy CameraEnumerator.java and Camera1Session.java and change them, probably keeping the package name